# How do you switch between pages with React-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a Menu, I need that when I click on an item the Menu disappears. I have seen a solution in this platform to create a `Pages` folder and there to put all the pages, but it does not allow me to do `import Menu from '. / Pages'`, I get an error: `cant resolve'. / Pages`. I am working with `react-router-dom`. Link de posible solution: [ReactJS How do you switch between pages in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649767/reactjs-how-do-you-switch-between-pages-in-react/49649856)
Link sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-bartik-jsjj9 line:12

Answer (score 3):

With the way you've structured your code, You'll have to do as you did for the 404 page:

`import MainMenu from "./pages/MainMenu";`

alternatively you can add an `index.js` file in the `pages` folder and export your components out if you want to keep the `./pages` style

i.e

```
index.js

export * from './MainMenu.js'
export * from './404.js'
...etc
```

Comment: look: [Youtube.com](https://youtu.be/hjR-ZveXBpQ?t=1054) and [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58672797/11281479)

Comment: If you look at his video closely, you'll notice there is a `index.jsx` file in the `pages` folder

Comment: Your question was regarding the error with the app not being able to resolve `./pages`, I believe my answer should resolve that issue. Are you having another problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your MainMenu.jsx file, you need to import React => **import React from "react";**

Then in your index.js file import the files as =>

1. import MainMenu from "./pages/MainMenu";
2. import NotFountPage from "./pages/404";
3. import Clients from "./pages/Clients";

Edit the index.js file and add the following code segment:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <MainMenu/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/404">
      <NotFountPage />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/clients">
      <Clients />
    </Route>
    <Redirect to="/404" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: mmmm, mi problem continues. I need my Menu to disappear when I click on Clientes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make a item disappear I will show you how.

```
import Nav from "./nav";



consturctor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state ={
    showNav: true
   }
}

render() {
  const show = this.state.showNav; // make a var to hold current state for this value
 return(
  {show ? <Nav />: null} // if show then show this component else show null
)
```

then make a function to change that state

```
dontShowNav = () => {
   this.setState({showNav: false});  // set show to false hide component
   }
}
```